# Insert row inside sql table based on its column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

i am having table `file` which contains multiple columns , one of them is `val` which was combination of 3 attributes `version,name and availability` all three are combined with `;` and stored inside `val` . Now i have to insert `3 rows` with coping all data and value i.e

```
id    file_id   file_version_id   val                  type

162   190234       259           1.2;DESC;AVAIL        desc
============================================================

id   file_id   file_version_id      val                type
162   190234       259             1.2                version

id   file_id   file_version_id      val                type
162   190234       259             DESC                name

 id   file_id   file_version_id     val                 type
162   190234       259              AVAIL           availability
```

As you can see from the example , i have to insert `3 records` with its data from parent row. The order of data is `version,name and availability` in case for some records `name` is not available i.e `3.4;NOT_AVAIL` then have to insert only two records with type `Version` and `availability`

Comment: Insert into the same table?

Comment: @forpas yes , in the file table only

Comment: If there are only 2 values like: xxx;yyy or 1 value zzz, how do you know which is which? If they are version,name or availability?

Comment: @forpas as i mentioned order is same `version,name and availability` if there is two consecutive string i.e `name and availabilty` if first one number other one string i.e version and name.

Comment: Which database do you really use? PL/SQL tag suggests Oracle, but - there are MySQL and PostgreSQL, so ...?

Comment: Using postgres `9.5`

Comment: *if first one number other one string i.e version and name.* why not version and availability like you mention in your question?

Comment: @RaushanSetthi  Please share what you have tried from your side.

Comment: @forpas `availablity ` could have max two val `AVAIL or NOT_AVAIL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNNEST()` to split the column `val` and a CASE expression to update the column `type`:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, file_id, file_version_id, val, type)
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(val, ';')) str
  FROM tablename                              
)
SELECT id, file_id, file_version_id, str,
  CASE
    WHEN str ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' THEN 'version'
    WHEN str IN ('AVAIL', 'NOT AVAIL') THEN 'availability'
    ELSE 'name'                   
  END
FROM cte;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ed9DaPwaRZvwYJenjoT9rE/0).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, it is the *positions* of the values in the string that determine the `type`, not their values.  I would suggest `unnest()` with the position and a `case` expression:

```
insert into file (id, file_id, file_version_id, val, type)
    select f.id, f.file_id, f.file_version_id, u.val,
           (case u.n 
                when 1 then 'version'
                when 2 then 'name'
                when 3 then 'availability'
            end)
    from file f cross join lateral
         unnest(string_to_array(f.val, ';')) with ordinality u(val, n);
```

If you want to be sure that all values are present, you might want `where f.val like '%;%;%'`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0e993ebf742fecec0696cacc00fa558) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: What is the error?  The `unnest()` is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0dffe7637a94debac576fb27d667bb69.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ed9DaPwaRZvwYJenjoT9rE/4 run this sql